# Wireguard not working on linux ubuntu

Tags: linux, vpn, wireguard

I have setup a vpn server in my house using pivpn and wireguard on a raspberry and I want to connect to it when I'm away.
I have generated the wireguard configuration which is working on all my devices (android, windows, macos) but not on linux ubuntu. I'm on the same internet connection with all my devices.

I have

```
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
```

I'm trying to connect using wg-quick up wg0.conf

Running wg prints out

```
interface: wg0
  public key: (hidden)
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 56359
  fwmark: 0xca6c

peer: F5qlHSEQl1tuMb6gyQrcB8+/4EDwU/DMymDo0bdbzGU=
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 2.235.232.194:51820
  allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
  transfer: 0 B received, 2.31 KiB sent
```

Comment: Can you please do `wg showconf wg0` on both the client and the server (with whatever ifc-name you use for wire-guard there) (... and remember to hide your private keys before posting it :-)

Comment: This is the client (I'm unable to do it on the server atm).

[Interface]
ListenPort = 37684
FwMark = 0xca6c
PrivateKey = (hidden)

[Peer]
PublicKey = (hidden)
PresharedKey = (hidden)
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = <server ip address>:51820